# Ios swift create a constructor for my class

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to swift and am using Swift 4.0 . I am trying to create a constructor for my class that takes 1 string parameter and am having issues getting it to work. I also get the error

> Incorrect argument label in call (have 'type:', expected 'coder:')

I have been moving things around but it's not working. I want to change my subclass below so that whenever I want to use that class the following signature would be required **CustomAVPLayerC(type: "string")** . This is my first time doing this since I normally work with functions.

This is my code

```
import UIKit
import AVKit

class CustomAVPLayerC: AVPlayerViewController {
    var ControllerType: String

   init(type: String) {
        self.ControllerType = type
        // perform some initialization here
       super.init(type: "")
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        if player?.isMuted == true {
            player?.isMuted = false
            //showsPlaybackControls = false

        } else {
            player?.isMuted = true

        }



    }

}
```

Comment: which line generates the error?

Comment: Unrelated to your issue but variable names should start with lowercase letters. Change `ControllerType` to `controllerType`.

Comment: Will change the variable name and the super.init(type: "") is throwing the error

Comment: Change `super.init(type: "")`  to `super.init()`, this is from BaseClass, your base class does not have  `super.init(type: "")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `init(type:)` initializer needs to call one of the `init` methods of the superclass `AVPlayerViewController`. `AVPlayerViewController` does not have an `init(type:)` initializer (that exists on your subclass).

Change:

```
super.init(type: "")
```

to:

```
super.init()
```

Comment: Oh Ok so essentially since my class is of type AVPlayerViewController  then I'll find an init from that one.

Comment: Yes, that is what `super` means - call the method from the base class.